# Random.nextInt(5) throws an IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, exception

### ***EDIT: SORRY!***

Turns out that I'm an idiot. The exception was being thrown from another call to r.nextInt() which was taking an uninitialized variable as an argument! Foot is very much in mouth.

I'm really not sure what else to say about this:

```
Random r = new Random();

class SomeClass {
   public SomeClass(){
       new SomeClass(r.nextInt(5));
   }

   public SomeClass(int i){
   ...
```

Throws a `NullPointerException` where r.nextInt(5) is called. Any ideas?

Comment: SomeClass is defined within SomeOtherClass, where Random r is declared.

Comment: Have you tried setting `r.nextInt(5)` to a variable and then passing the variable inside the constructor?

Comment: [NullPointerException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) != [IllegalArgumentException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)

Comment: You're not really showing your code, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I'm an idiot. The exception was being thrown from another call to r.nextInt() on the same line which was taking an uninitialized variable as an argument! Foot is very much in mouth. Will read more carefully in future.

Comment: No problem, things like that have happened to all of us. :-) Please mark your clarification as "accepted answer" (by clicking on the check mark), so that your question no longer shows up as "unanswered".

Comment: +1 for the confession.  As Heinzi says, please accept your own  response, as a favour to future seekers who might have made the same bloomer.

Comment: I can't accept it for another 23 hours it says

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), nextInt only throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if the parameter is not positive.

My guess is it that you are *not* calling it with a literal constant 5, but rather with some variable that happens to be zero (or negative).

Comment: I rather guess that r itself is null.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do with this,

```
  public SomeClass(){
       new SomeClass(r.nextInt(5));
   }
```

but I suspect the correct syntax (if you want to call the other constructor) is

```
  public SomeClass(){
       this(r.nextInt(5));
   }
```

You should post the code of the outside class to understand your problem.

Comment: It's not the subject of his problem. (It's highly possible that it's what he was going to do, even though what he did is also completly correct).

Comment: That doesn't explain the NPE. (Indeed, that would always NPE with `-target 1.3` or less.)

Comment: Yes, I know this this does not explain the NPE, but it's surely a bug nonetheless

Comment: Then add it is a comment. (Actually, what I said about 1.3 isn't true. It would be true in a situation involving base classes.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing your problem with the sample code. But it works..

import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test1 = new Test();
    SomeClass obj = test1.new SomeClass();
}

private Random r = new Random();

class SomeClass {
       public SomeClass(){
           new SomeClass(r.nextInt(5));
       }

       public SomeClass(int i){
           System.out.println(i);
       }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but this code compiles and runs without an NPE. You need to show the code that is a problem. Extract from your current code a short example that demonstrates the issue.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SomeOtherClass {
    Random r = new Random();

    class SomeClass {
        public SomeClass() {
            /***/
            new SomeClass(r.nextInt(5));
            /*/
            this(r.nextInt(5)); // Or this.
            /***/
        }

        public SomeClass(int i){
            // ...
        }
    }

    public SomeOtherClass() {
        new SomeClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeOtherClass();
    }
}
```